# wordpress feed link change

Tags: feed

This is my default feed link

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="&quot; WordPress Local Development Environment&quot; &raquo; Feed" href="https://127.0.0.0/feed" />
```

I would like to change the URL to [https://127.0.0.0/?rss=y"](https://127.0.0.0/?rss=y%22)

Comment: Do you mean just change the URL in the link, or do you mean set up WordPress to understand ?rss=y too? At first glance that doesn't work on my site.

Comment: You can use ?feed=rss, although that will redirect to /feed/ by default. To stop that you'll have to change / filter get_feed_permastruct. But I'm not sure you can adapt that to your use the ?rss=y scheme.

Comment: thank you, I have added the following filter and its working: function filter_feed_link( $feed ) { 
  
  $url  = site_url();
  $feed = $url . '/?rss=y';
  return $feed;
 }